# GridView scrolling weird issue

Tags: android, performance, gridview

let me explain my problem.

I'm using a GridView with a custom adapter, and everything works fine. As the title says the problem comes when I scroll fast.

Scrolling slow works perfectly, but when I scroll fast and reach end I've got like a "kickback" to the middle of the grid, but this problem doesn't apear when I scroll fast from the back to the top.

I'm coding for 2.3.3 using 4.2 sdk version. 
I'm testing on a 2.3.3 real phone and on a 4.2 emulator, same results.

Thanks for your futur answer ! (Sorry for my poor written English)

Here you are the code of my adapter.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class RadioAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Radio> radios;  
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public RadioAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Radio> radios) {
        this.context = context;
        this.radios = radios;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    } 

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return radios.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Radio getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        Radio radio = radios.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();          

            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_cover);

            convertView.setTag(holder);                  
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag(); 
        }   

        holder.textView.setText(radio.getName());

        holder.imageView.setImageResource(radio.getThumbnail());

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

**EDIT3:**

After some more research I've found this : https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/issues/282

> Are you using android:overScrollMode="never"? There is a bug in
>   scroller implementation in Gingerbread: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15860

So the problem I have is normal on Gingerbread, damn.

I've tested with a 4.0.3 phone and it works normally. Problem solved.

**EDIT2:**

I've detected that the problem comes with

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

**EDIT:**

Here you are my layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/top_bar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:gravity="center" />  

        <censored.RadioView
            android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"     
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:columnWidth="100dp"
            android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/grid_selector"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:scrollbars="none">
        </censored.RadioView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And the code of my RadioView

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class RadioView extends GridView{
    private Bitmap background;

    public RadioView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public RadioView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public RadioView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    protected void init() {
        background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.shelfcell_bgr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int top = getChildCount() > 0 ? getChildAt(0).getTop() : 0;
        for (int y = top; y < getHeight(); y += background.getHeight()){
            for (int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x += background.getWidth()){
                canvas.drawBitmap(background, x, y, null);
            }
        }
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Post your xml layout for further investigation.

Comment: @Christos I have updated my question with the layout I use, and the RadioView element code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I've found this : 
https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/issues/282

> Are you using android:overScrollMode="never"? There is a bug in
>   scroller implementation in Gingerbread:
>   http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15860

So the problem I have is normal on Gingerbread, damn.

I've tested with a 4.0.3 phone and it works normally. Problem solved.